# Why fstream prints out last record of a file

Tags: c++, binary, fstream

why is it that the last record of a binary file is being printed out twice?

```
while( (inFile)
{
    inFile.read(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&acc), sizeof(acc));  
    display(acc);
}
```

Comment: For similar reasons, as outlined in [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: You are displaying the result, disregarding the success of the reading.

Answer (score 2):

Because your code should read

```
while (inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&acc), sizeof(acc))
{
    display(acc);
}
```

Your version only tests for failure **after** you've printed the failed read. Or to put it another way `while (infile)` is not a test that the next read will succeed, it's a test that the last read succeeded.